# Is there a way to append one svn trunk onto another, including the change history?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have a developer who got a little ambitious, and didn't understand branching in SVN and came up with their own solution. They needed to make a big change, but didn't want to impede any bug fixes in the main trunk. So, they created a new folder at the same level as main project folder for this change.

The original looks like this (at rev 100)

```
/bigProj/branch
        /tag
        /trunk/config
              /docs
              /src
```

and the new folder looks like this (at rev 150)

```
/bigProjChange/trunk/config
                    /docs
                    /src
```

What I'd love to do, is airlift the contents of `bigProjChange` either into a branch of `bigProj` or append those ~50 revisions onto the end of the trunk of `bigProj` (there were no bug fixes, so this creativity served no purpose). And then blow away `bigProjChange` because of the confusion it is causing.

Is there a way to do this and keep the changes/comments from everything that happened in `bigProjChange`? Or am I stuck taking the contents of Rev 150 of `bigProjChange` and doing a mas update of `bigProj`'s trunk?

Comment: Are `bigProj` and `bigProjChanged` in the same Subversion repository or are these two different repositories? If so, how was `bigProjChanged` created?

Answer (score 1):

If both `bigProj` and `bigProjChanged` live in the same repository, you can simply `svn merge` them as you would with any branch. Keep in mind the so-called *standard layout* with `trunk`/`branches`/`tags` is purely by convention. To Subversion, the directory names don't make a difference.

The easy way to resolve this is as you would do any reintegrate-merge:

```bash
svn switch ^/bigProj/trunk
svn merge ^/bigProjChanged/trunk .
# resolve conflicts, if any
svn commit -m"Reintegrate bigProjChanged"

svn rm ^/bigProjChanged -m"Blow away!"
```